# scraping incomplete tables with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am very new to python so I apologize in advance if this is a simple fix. 
I am trying to scrape the table shown here: https://www.opensecrets.org/lobby/lobbyist.php?id=Y0000008510L&year=2018
This is the code I am using:

```
import requests
page=requests.get("https://www.opensecrets.org/lobby/lobbyist.php?id=Y0000008510L&year=2018")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table=soup.table
```

However, it is not recognizing the entire table. Here is the print(table) output from python:

```
   <table class="datadisplay" id="lobbyist_summary" style="margin-top:40px;">
<thead><tr><th class="data">Lobbying Firm</th></tr></thead></table>
```

How do I get it to recognize the entire table? Eventually, I would like to end up with a .txt or .csv file that closely resembles the table on the webpage but I am currently stuck at this step. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `soup.find('table', {'id': 'lobbyist_summary'})` work? If not, you may try changing your parser from `'html.parser'` to `'lxml'`

Comment: Is the table that you want actually in the HTML, or is it generated by JavaScript code after the page is loaded? If the latter, then you can't scrape it this way; you either need to interpret the JS, drive a browser with something like Selenium, or read the JS code to figure out what APIs it's calling and call them directly from Python.

Comment: If the problem is just that the HTML is broken, a different parser might help, but you also might be able to get away with searching for the `tbody`, or `find_all('tr')`, or something like that, depending on how it's broken.

Comment: Thank you rahlf23. Changing to 'lxml' did the trick!